# How to use different retrofit libraries in a project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit

One of library is using `retrofit:1.9.0` and one is using `retrofit:2.0.0` if i disable any of it, the library that is using it crashes. If i add both of them like following

> ```
> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
> ```

The app starts crashing on lollipop devices.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lretrofit2/Retrofit$Builder;

and if I remove `1.9.0`, the library that is using it crashes.

So i have to use both retrofit libraries in my project.

Is it possible to  add different version of libraries without create conflict.

Comment: If you have both, you should get duplicate errors, not "no class found"

Comment: what is the name of libraries that are using the different versions of retrofit? Could you fork one of them and update it?

Comment: @cricket_007 I get `->` in gradle tree, but  as soon as i add both of `retrofit` version, i get `classDefNotFound` error message

Comment: @Blundell the one that is using older version is a private libraries, I got `aar` files from client. The other one is twitter,its using `retrofit 2.0.2`

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` files.